# Can Profile2 present fields on registration?

Tags: 7, users

I'm looking at using Profile2 on a D7 site, so that we can have private fields, and different fields per role.

Is it possible to have Profile2 present its fields on the user registration page? New users are going to default to a particular role, so the fields would be that of the default role.

I've looked at the [introductory](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1074296) pages, but they are very sparse. All I could find for configuring Profile2 on a site where it's installed was simply specifying the per-role fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a checkbox in the profile settings if it should be displayed in the user registration form. At Structure > Profile types > edit.